# How to search multiple custom fields by one string in Odoo?

Tags: filter, odoo, odoo-8

I created a custom odoo module and now I want to make a search filter that makes it easy to search multiple fields at the same time. I added this code to my xml and I am able to search each field individually but would like to group them into one string so the user can search all the fields (mfr name 1-6) with one search. Does anybody know if this is possible?

```xml
<record id="product_template_search_custom_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.template.customsearch</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_search_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="/search/field[@name='name']" position="before"> 
           <field name="x_mfrname1" string="Mfr Name1"/>
           <field name="x_mfrname2" string="Mfr Name2"/>
           <field name="x_mfrname3" string="Mfr Name3"/>
           <field name="x_mfrname4" string="Mfr Name4"/>
           <field name="x_mfrname5" string="Mfr Name5"/>
           <field name="x_mfrname6" string="Mfr Name6"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `filter_domain` attribute

```xml
<record id="product_template_search_custom_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">product.template.customsearch</field>
    <field name="model">product.template</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_search_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="name" position="replace"> 
            <field name="name" filter_domain="['|', '|', '|', '|', '|', ('x_mfrname1','ilike',self), ('x_mfrname2','ilike',self), ('x_mfrname3','ilike',self), ('x_mfrname4','ilike',self), ('x_mfrname5','ilike',self), ('x_mfrname5','ilike',self)]" />
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

For further information check [the Odoo Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html#reference-views-search)

Comment: Don't forget the "old" fields of the original domain_filter, if you want just want to extend that search with your fields.